# How can you extract type information from a Proxy?

Tags: haskell

Let's say I have a standard [proxy](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Proxy.html) with some type `a` hidden inside:

```
pxyA = Proxy :: Proxy a
```

Because of other parts of my program, I know for a fact that `a` is actually a tuple of two other types, say `(b,c)`. Is there any way for me to extract that information from my original proxy with a function like:

```
f :: Proxy a -> (Proxy b, Proxy c)
```

or

```
f :: Proxy a -> Proxy (b,c)
```

The main thing stopping me is that I don't know what the types `b` or `c` are going to be, just that I need to pass them to other parts of my program.

I've already written a trivial function with a similar form:

```
splitPxyTup :: forall a b . Proxy (a,b) -> (Proxy a, Proxy b)
splitPxyTup _ = (Proxy :: Proxy a, Proxy :: Proxy b)
```

but keep getting lost on how to convince the type system that my original proxy actually is a tuple type.

I also thought about using a `cast`, but since I don't know what the output types are, I won't be able to get anything meaningful from it.

Comment: I don't think a function `f` is useful, but maybe you are just looking for an equality constraint: `a ~ (b,c) => ... Proxy a ...`? More information on your use case would definitely help!

Comment: Hmmm I didn't think about a constraint like that, it might work with what I'm trying, I'll give it a shot. I'm happy to give more information, I have a recursive function that is piecing together functions based on proxy types, and need to handle the case where an input type is a tuple. I can identify that case, but since everything is polymorphic, I can't just cast things to a specific type to then pull out the `(b,c)`. I can't go into too much detail, but let me know if that's not clear.

Comment: If you aren't certain at compile time that you'll have a tuple, you'll probably want overlapping classes instead. Otherwise, the equality constraint should do it.

Comment: Everything happens inside of `MonadPlus` to allow for backtracking if you don't get a tuple, I have other cases to handle the other portions. Inside of the tuple portion, I'm certain it's a tuple, but I'm having trouble convincing the compiler to allow me to break `Proxy a` into `Proxy (b,c)` since `b` and `c` are unknown types. The equality constraints works on it's own, but it won't compile at a call site. Is there a way for me to use that kind of constraint to do something like `a ~ (b,c) => a -> Maybe (b,c)`?

Comment: How does the tuple portion detect that it's a tuple? That seems to be the key.

Comment: Extremely hacky typeRep comparisons. I don't like how it happens right now, but it works for the detection. We can do `Proxy a -> TypeRep` and do comparisons at the `TypeRep` level. But we can't get back from `TypeRep -> Proxy a`. I started to look at the [reflection](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflection) library, but that doesn't seem to do what I need.

Comment: Now I'm getting really curious. Do you have any of this on Github by any chance? You could be looking for [`withTypeable :: forall a r. TypeRep a -> (Typeable a => r) -> r`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/master/libraries/html/base/Type-Reflection.html#v:withTypeable) in the new `Type.Reflection` module.

Comment: None of this code unfortunately, it's all proprietary right now. My coworker gave a talk about this idea at lambdaconf this last year, but the video's aren't online yet either. That function might be what I need, I hadn't run across that module yet.

Comment: Seconding @Alec: you want the new `Typeable` stuff that gives you type-level witnesses of the term-level information in the `TypeRep`. Or, if you absolutely can't use a new GHC, emulate it yourself with a hand implementation of (a clone of) the `Typeable` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been trying to see what you're after and can't quite, it would be helpful if you could produce a more complete example that represents your problem.

Until then, I seem to have an answer for this part of your question

> The main thing stopping me is that I don't know what the types `b` or `c` are going to be...

From that sentence it sounds like you need an existential:

```
proxyTuple :: Proxy a -> exists b c. Proxy (b,c)
```

which is not valid Haskell, but we can encode it easily:

```
data ProxyTupleEx where
    ProxyTupleEx :: Proxy (b,c) -> ProxyTupleEx
```

It's not quite enough though, because we could easily implement this function in a trivial way.

```
proxyTuple :: Proxy a -> ProxyTupleEx
proxyTuple _ = ProxyTupleEx (Proxy :: Proxy ((), ()))
```

We need to also specify the connection with the incoming `a`.  This we can do:

```
data ProxyTupleEx a where
    ProxyTupleEx :: (a ~ (b,c)) => Proxy (b,c) -> ProxyTupleEx a
```

We won't be able to implement `proxyTuple` now, because it has no implementation when `a` is not a tuple.  We need

```
proxyTuple :: Proxy a -> Maybe (ProxyTupleEx a)
```

giving it the opportunity to fail.

Now we get to your [other question about reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48158787/how-can-you-decompose-compose-types-using-the-type-reflection-library).  We need to add a `Typeable` constraint so that we can reflect about the type, but then it is fairly straightforward once you are used to the cadence of the library:

```
proxyTuple :: Typeable a => Proxy a -> Maybe (ProxyTupleEx a)
proxyTuple p
    | App _proxy (App (App tuple a) b) <- typeOf p
    , Just HRefl <- eqTypeRep tuple (typeRep :: TypeRep (,))
    = Just (ProxyTupleEx p)
    | otherwise
    = Nothing
```

Now if you pattern match on a `ProxyTupleEx a`, the compiler will know that `a` is actually a tuple.

```
tupleLength :: (a,b) -> Int
tupleLength _ = 2

example :: Typeable a => Proxy a -> a -> Int
example proxy x
    | Just (ProxyTupleEx _) <- proxyTuple proxy = tupleLength x
                                                  -- x is now known to be a tuple
                                                  -- so this typechecks
    | otherwise = 0
```

Like magic, this typechecks, and works:

```
ghci> example Proxy (1,2)
2
ghci> example Proxy 0
0
```

(Also the `Proxy` here is unnecessary since we already have the type of `a`, but I included it for consistency with the query.)

Comment: So I've been trying to use your example, but I'm running into issues actually using the underlying typereps. In your `tupleLength`, you just return an int and ignore the types `a` and `b`. Overall, I'm trying to create a function that can take the arbitrary `TypeRep` (I wrote this question before knowing about Type.Reflection in GHC 8.2, that's why it asks with `Proxy`) and return the underlying typereps. I.e. `TypeRep a -> Maybe (TypeRep b, TypeRep c)`. I can get things to work with specific, concrete types like `@(Int,Char)` but not polymorphic types. Any thoughts?

Comment: The fact that I return an `Int` eventually is essential.  It is required to eliminate the existential type variables somehow.  We don't have to *ignore* them altogether like `tupleLength` does, but they can't be part of the return type, because that would make it impossible to give `example` a type that Haskell supports (since it does not support first-class existentials). At best, we can wrap them up in another existential data type (like `ProxyTupleEx`)

Comment: FWIW the signature `TypeRep a -> Maybe (TypeRep b, TypeRep c)` is not correct for what you are looking for.  This signature says that the *caller* chooses `b` and `c`, but you want the them rather to be chosen by the *callee*.  That's why all this existential stuff is coming up.

Comment: I think the caller/callee distinction is really what's giving me trouble. In my program, I need to split a given typerep into its components, and then pass those components as arguments to other functions. I still feel like it's possible, but getting all of the types to line up is tricky.

Answer (score 0):

This seems easy enough to write, given the limited context available from your question. As long as you can provide a concrete proof of your claim that `a ~ (b, c)`, you just need a bit of `Data.Type.Equality` machinery to convince GHC.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, TypeOperators #-}

import Data.Proxy
import Data.Type.Equality

splitProxyTuple :: a :~: (b, c) -> Proxy a -> Proxy (b, c)
splitProxyTuple Refl = castWith Refl
```

and using it in a GHCI session

```
> type T = (Int, Char)
> type F = (Int, Bool)
> let prf = Refl :: (T :~: (Int, Char))
> let prx = Proxy :: Proxy T

> :t splitProxyTuple prf prx
splitProxyTuple prf prx :: Proxy (Int, Char)
=> Proxy

> :t splitProxyTuple prf (Proxy :: Proxy F)
  • Couldn't match type ‘Bool’ with ‘Char’
    Expected type: Proxy T
      Actual type: Proxy F
  • In the second argument of ‘splitProxyTuple’, namely
      ‘(Proxy :: Proxy F)’
    In the expression: splitProxyTuple prf (Proxy :: Proxy F)
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the problem with this is you have to provide the `(b,c)` that you want to extract don't you?

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely understand what you're asking, but this function doesn't depend on any specific `b`, `c`. Given you can provide a `Refl :: a :~: (b, c)` value, and you use the values `x :: b` and `y :: c` in a non-ambiguous context (say as non-parametric arguments to a function) then I believe GHC should be able to infer the types. Again, difficult to answer without more context or a code example.

Comment: I won't have values for `x` or `y`, just proxies, and I don't know what they will be (so a partially ambiguous context). I need to take my `Proxy a`, and, knowing `a` is really a tuple of `(b,c)`, split it into two proxies `Proxy b` and `Proxy c`.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I think my answer has missed the point of your question then. I'm not sure how you can know that `a ~ (b, c)` without knowing what `b`, `c` are. Or furthermore, what good is a `Proxy b` without knowing, or being able to infer, a concrete type for `b`.

Comment: Maybe a little bit, I'll look more into `Data.Type.Equality` and see if it contains any answers to help me out further. If you have suggestions on how to improve the clarity of my question, I'm happy to apply or accept edits! I can know that `a ~ (b,c)` by casting the proxies to typereps and comparing the type constructors. Once I get there though, I can't get back to generate new proxies. `Proxy b` is useful in my situation since I can use it as a selector for other recursive function calls moving on in my application. It doesn't have to be a rigid type for me to know how to use it.