# How can you decompose/compose types using the Type.Reflection library?

Tags: haskell

<sub>This is related to a [previous question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46348867/how-can-you-extract-type-information-from-a-proxy), where I was directed to the new functionality in GHC 8.2.</sub>

---

The new (in base 4.10) [Type.Reflection](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Type-Reflection.html) library claims:

> The interface provides TypeRep, a type representation which can be safely decomposed and composed. See [Data.Dynamic](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-Dynamic.html) for an example of this.

`Data.Dynamic` shows a way to safely compose/decompose values using `TypeRep` and checking for type-level equality. In my case, I'd like to inspect and return the underlying types of a given `TypeRep`.

It's easy to peek into a type to see what makes it up now using a variety of tools. One of which is the function `splitApps :: TypeRep a -> (TyCon, [SomeTypeRep])`.

The problem seems to be that any way I can look into a `TypeRep` only provides back the non-indexed version of the type: `SomeTypeRep`. So, I looked around and found `mkTrCon :: forall k (a :: k). TyCon -> [SomeTypeRep] -> TypeRep a` which has the exact type signature I'm looking for and allows me to rebuild a `TypeRep` from its constituent parts! Except, it's not exposed by the module.

So what am I missing? Is there a way to actually rebuild a `TypeRep` from `SomeTypeRep` (i.e. `f :: SomeTypeRep -> TypeRep a`) or to get the underlying `TypeRep`'s that build up a type? Do I just need to copy the source of `Data.Typeable.Internal` to get access to the functions I want to use?

Comment: Looks like the [pattern synonyms](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Type-Reflection.html#v:App) in the library are what you need

Comment: Aren't those only for pattern matching? Not construction?

Comment: @luqui Nevermind. Just tried it in GHCi and it definitely worked. Can't remember why I thought that. I'll see if I get it working with the pattern synonyms.

Comment: @luqui Tried it this morning again and realized what I did wrong. the `pattern App` is bi-directional, but `Con` and `Con'` are not. If you try to use them as constructors you get the following error message: "non-bidirectional pattern synonym Con' used in an expression"

Comment: ah yeah, because `TyCon` has no type information about the constructor, so there's no way to reflect it to the type level.  But using e.g. `(typeRep :: TypeRep Maybe)` works fine to construct a literal constructor rep.

Comment: @luqui Is there a way to infer the `Maybe` portion of your example from a `(TyCon, [SomeTypeRep])`? That's what I would need to be able to reconstruct the type reps I think.

Comment: Haskell is not dependenly typed, so there is no way for information to flow from the value level to the type level like that.   Besides, in asking this question, you have already lost the connection between the `TyCon` and the type it represents ... it's unclear how you would use this inference to your advantage even if you could.